# Virgo "Greenpages" small change issue

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-virgo

first of all I would like to say that I'm newbie to Virgo and OSGi so please be patient ;)

Here's my problem: I'm playing with the "greenpages" lastes version (http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/greenpages-documentation-2.4.0.RELEASE/docs/htmlsingle/greenpages-guide.html) sample project and I would like to change object passing form jpa subproject project to web subproject. My change look like this:

```
<osgi:service ref="directory" interface="greenpages.jpa.JpaDirectory"/>
```

instead of

```
<osgi:service ref="directory" interface="greenpages.Directory"/>
```

and in web project context :

```
<osgi:reference id="directory" interface="greenpages.jpa.JpaDirectory" />
```

where Directory is an interface and JpaDirecotry is implementation, so in my web conroller I would like to have something like this:

```
@Controller
public class GreenPagesController {

    @Autowired
    private JpaDirectory directory;
....

}
```

I was forced to change JpaDirectory class accessor from default to "public". But I still receive error:

[2013-03-10 13:51:59.047] ERROR start-signalling-11          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader                     Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'directory': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'interfaces'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [greenpages.jpa.JpaDirectory]

and have no idea how to handle it. Maybe someone can advice me what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your bundle is not importing the package `greenpages.jpa`. Make sure that `greenpages.jpa` is added to the `Import-Package` header in your bundle's MANIFEST.MF.